# Invalid Column Name en una tabla creada con Querys en un Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, subconsultas

Quiero crear un SP con dos parámetros, Fecha y Banco, el propósito es que por cada Banco debe mostrarse (entre otros datos) todos los clientes en ese banco y el monto del efectivo que tendrá disponible en 24,48 y 72 horas después del parámetro Fecha. La cuestión es que tengo una tabla donde se almacenan unos datos generales de las cuentas y otra tabla donde almaceno los flujos, de la segunda tabla "calculo" el flujo futuro que habrá para cada periodo (24,48,72)
 y trato que me muestre esto en una tabla temporal de 3 columnas, luego trato de unir esta tabla con la de datos generales con un `left join`. Lo que tengo  tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE .dbo.SALDOS_24_48_72 @pmInstitución nvarchar(25), @pmFechaDeConsulta date
  as
  Declare @24hrs date,@48hrs date, @72hrs date, @96hrs date
  , @pmFechadeConsulta date='2017-02-14'                --EJEMPLO
    DECLARE @pmInstitución nvarchar(50)='Banco' --EJEMPLO

    Set @24hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --24 horas después de la fecha de consulta
    Set @48hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,2,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --48 horas después de la fecha de consulta
    Set @72hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,3,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --72 horas después de la fecha de consulta
    Set @96hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,4,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --96 horas después de la fecha de consulta 
    ;
WITH #Liquidacion as (
(SELECT SUM(importe) as UnDia,A.Cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and Liquidacion>@pmFechaDeConsulta and liquidacion< @48hrs GROUP BY A.Cliente)            --Efectivo 24 hrs
UNION
(SELECT SUM(importe) as DosDias,A.Cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and Liquidacion> @24hrs and liquidacion< @72hrs  GROUP BY A.Cliente)                      --Efectivo 48 hrs
UNION
(SELECT SUM(importe) as TresDias,A.cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and Liquidacion> @48hrs and liquidacion< @96hrs  GROUP BY A.Cliente)                      --Efectivo 72 hrs
) 
SELECT  A.Cliente,A.Alias,Cuenta,Valor,Saldo,C.UnDia,C.DosDias,C.TresDias FROM CuentasEDGE A LEFT JOIN Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave LEFT JOIN #Liquidacion C ON A.Cliente=C.Cliente  WHERE 
B.Activo=1 and A.Proveedor=@pmInstitución
```

En las Declaraciones uso un ejemplo de fecha y Banco para ejecutar el código pero me regresa un ERROR:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 Invalid column name 'DosDias'. Msg
>   207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 Invalid column name 'TresDias'.

Es decir que no reconoce los valores de la tabla temporal. Una cuestión que observé es que no tengo registros en la tabla de flujos para 48 y 72 horas ¿es el hecho de estar vacías estas columnas el porqué del error? ¿existe una mejor forma de generar esta tabla final? Quiero que, al final, tenga esta forma:

> Cliente | Alias | Cuenta | Valor | Saldo | 24hrs | 48 hrs | 72 hrs
>
> 00001   |  Rojo   |  000666 | 1421  | 63.50 | 125 |   0   |   0   |

Comment: El tema es que estas haciendo un Union con nombres de columna diferentes, recorda que al hacer un Union los nombres de columnas que trae cada una de las consultas deberían ser iguales, y en tu caso usas el nombre Undia para una DosDias para otra y TresDias para la ultima, aparentemente la cte no arroja ese error pero te toma sola una.

Comment: @HectorScesa,¿Entonces cómo podría diferenciarlos? quiero que sean 3 columnas, una por cada periodo.

Comment: Ahi te agrego un ejemplo en la respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaria variables de Tabla. Es mas rápida que que una tabla temporal y muy practica y se comporta exactamente como una tabla. Tampoco tienes que preocuparte de destruirla

```
CREATE PROCEDURE .dbo.SALDOS_24_48_72 @pmInstitución nvarchar(25), 
@pmFechaDeConsulta date
  as
  Declare @24hrs date,@48hrs date, @72hrs date, @96hrs date
  , @pmFechadeConsulta date='2017-02-14'                --EJEMPLO
  DECLARE @pmInstitución nvarchar(50)='Banco' --EJEMPLO

  Declare @Liquidacion table (cliente int,UnDia int,DosDias 
  int,TresDias int)


  Set @24hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --24 horas 
después de la fecha de consulta
  Set @48hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,2,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --48 horas 
después de la fecha de consulta
  Set @72hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,3,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --72 horas 
después de la fecha de consulta
  Set @96hrs=(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,4,@pmFechaDeConsulta)) --96 horas 
después de la fecha de consulta 

insert into @Liquidacion
SELECT SUM(importe) as UnDia,0 as DosDias,0 as TresDias,A.Cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT 
JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join 
pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and 
Liquidacion>@pmFechaDeConsulta and liquidacion< @48hrs GROUP BY 
A.Cliente)            
UNION
(SELECT 0 as UnDia,SUM(importe) as DosDias,0 as TresDias,A.Cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT 
JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join 
pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and Liquidacion> @24hrs and 
liquidacion< @72hrs  GROUP BY A.Cliente)                      
UNION
(SELECT 0 as UnDIa,0 as DosDias,SUM(importe) as TresDias,A.cliente from MovimientosEDGE A LEFT 
JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave Left join 
pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C on A.Cliente=C.Cliente WHERE 
C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución and B.Activo=1 and Liquidacion> @48hrs and 
liquidacion< @96hrs  GROUP BY A.Cliente)                      

SELECT  
A.Cliente,A.Alias,Cuenta,Valor,Saldo,C.UnDia,C.DosDias,C.TresDias 
FROM 
CuentasEDGE A 
LEFT JOIN Clientes B ON A.Cliente=B.Clave 
LEFT JOIN @Liquidacion C ON A.Cliente=C.Cliente  
WHERE B.Activo=1 and A.Proveedor=@pmInstitución
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Le agregue una correccion al union para que tengan el mismo formato que la variable de tabla/tabla temporal, agregandole 0 en los campos UnDia, DosDias,TresDias como se daran cuenta. Esto te dara como resultado 3 registros uno por cada dia. Si deseas todo en una sola fila hay que hacer un group by otra vez de los 3 unions

Comment: Claro, de esta forma si no hay valores, me pone 0 en vez de NULL cierto?

Comment: si correcto, y para que no te de problemas a la hora de insertar en la tabla por algun constraint que puede pasar

Comment: Una cosa más: Existe la posibilidad de que existan cuentas que no tienen flujos registrados, entonces la tabla `@liquidacion` da null para todos las columnas de ese cliente pero quisiera evitar esto y que simplemente ponga 0 ¿tienes alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

El problema ya te lo indicó correctamente Hector en los comentarios, estás haciendo un union pero retornas una única columna, para lo que buscas, debieras modificar esta consulta por una sumatoria condicional. Algo así:

```
WITH #Liquidacion as (
(
    SELECT  
        SUM(CASE WHEN                           Liquidacion< @48hrs THEN importe ELSE 0) as UnDia,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Liquidacion >= @48hrs AND Liquidacion< @72hrs THEN importe ELSE 0) as DosDia,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Liquidacion >= @72hrs AND Liquidacion< @96hrs THEN importe ELSE 0) as TresDia
        A.Cliente 
        from MovimientosEDGE A 
        LEFT JOIN  pruebaEDGE.dbo.Clientes B 
            ON A.Cliente=B.Clave 
        Left join pruebaEDGE.dbo.CuentasEDGE C 
            on A.Cliente=C.Cliente 
        WHERE C.Proveedor=@pmInstitución 
            and B.Activo=1 
            and Liquidacion>@pmFechaDeConsulta and liquidacion<@96hrs
        GROUP BY A.Cliente
)
```